# Adding text from one field to another in QGIS attribute table?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

[image]

I would like to copy names from field 'Uch_1' to 'Uchastok' but not all. Names in 'Uch_1' should be copied and replace only  where in 'Uchastok' cells  are 'NULL'  but if not, it remains without changes.

Any ideas what code should I use in Field Calculator?

Answer (score 4):

there are a few options

**First**

Select all cells with value 'NULL'

Open field calculator

- You will see the first option checked: 'only update xxx selected features'.  Keep it checked!!
- check 'update existing field'
- select 'Uchastok'

In the expression panel add "Uch_1"

Press 'OK'

**Second**

- check 'update existing field'
- select 'Uchastok'

Add following code:

> case
>
> when "Uchastok" is null then "Uch_1"
>
> else "Uchastok"
>
> end